# Why do we need to create an IP header on a LAN?

Tags: ip, ethernet, subnet

I understand that ARP is used to map IP addresses to MAC addresses and that on an Ethernet/Layer 2 network the MAC is used to address other computers. I get if a client wants to talk to server that's on another network it will need to address the IP address that's representative of it.

So on the same network PC 1 has mapped PC 2 to an IP/MAC address, why does it need to create an IP header that's not going to be used by PC 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP addresses are used not only for transmission between hosts. They are also used for host identification on higher levels. For example: when new TCP connection is established to server server can identify source of the request (by client IP address/port).

Also it is good idea not to distinguish local and wide network connections it is easier to implement all protocol things once.

By the way - in some situations IP-addresses are really skipped during transmission between hosts. For example in case of PPP with header compression. But this situations are not very common.